# What does the else statement changing the counter do?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, motion

My instructions are to track a person's motion forward and backward (every step they take). Total steps are generated from 10-85, forward and backward steps max range is between 2-20. Forward steps must always be greater than backward.

So I wrote the code for this program and my colleague corrected my code. I can't seem to figure out what the else statement does? else: f= fwd??
Does it change f=f+1 to f=fwd+1? I just need a clarification on this.

For example: If the program generated the forward steps to be 4, and the backward steps to be 2, and the total number of steps to be 13, your program would display:
FFFFBBFFFFBBF = 5 Steps from the start

```
     import random
while True:
    fwd= random.randint(2,20)
    bkwd= random.randint(2,fwd-1)
    total=random.randint(10,85)
    f= 0
    b = 0
    t= 0
    steps_taken= 0

    if bkwd > fwd:
        break

    while total > 0:
        f = 0
 #Generating forward steps
         while fwd > f:
             if total > 0:
                print("F", end="")
                f=f+1
                t=t+1
                total=total-1
                steps_taken= steps_taken+1
 #I'm having trouble here
            else:
               f = fwd
               t = t
               total = total
               steps_taken= steps_taken

        b = 0
  #Generating backward steps
        while bkwd > b:
            if total > 0:
                print("B", end="")
                t=t-1
                b=b+1
                total=total-1
                steps_taken= steps_taken+1
            else:
               b = bkwd
               t = t
               total = total
               steps_taken = steps_taken
           
     if f > total or b > total:
        break

print(" ",t, "steps from the start")
print("Forward:", f, "Backward:", b, "Total:", steps_taken )
```

Comment: I'm not keen to reverse engineer some uncommented code. [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I commented on it now

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that could be improved there, like this:

```
t = t
total = total
steps_taken= steps_taken
```

it has no (visible) effect and can be just removed!

But moving to an answer to your question, its main purpose is to exit the loop. Notice that when `total` is less than steps we need to take, we never exit `while fwd > f` loop because at some point `total == 0`. However the correct way should be

```
else:
    break
```

And in last `print` statement use `fwd/bkwd` instead of `f/b`.